# Verbments: listofpyglistings numwidth

Tags: table-of-contents, chngcntr, verbments

im really new to latex and now have tryed to make an List of my SourceCode. To Highlight I used verbments. It provides the Command ListOfPyglist. This works fine. Now I want to set the Counter to count within section, subsection and subsubsection. 
This also works fine, but now there is one Problem:
When I make the ListOf the Listing looks ugly because the numbering overlaps the Captions. I had the same problem with figures and Tables, but there I solved it with

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2em}
```

This works fine. Previously I used the Package listings and there I solved the Issue with the Numbering with

```
\makeatletter
    \let\l@lstlisting\l@figure
\makeatother
```

So I thought i could fix it in my pyglisting with the same way...

```
\makeatletter
    \let\l@pyglist\l@figure
\makeatother
```

But It didn't work. So I looked at the Source of verbments... And there I found the line which makes probably the line:

```
\newcommand{\l@pyglist}[2]{%
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}
}
```

So I thought if i renew the command it should work...

```
\makeatletter
    \renewnewcommand{\l@pyglist}{%
        \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.3em}
    }
\makeatother
```

But didn't affect..

So, does anybody know a Solution?

Here is an short sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,toc=listof,toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{verbments}

\plset{
    style=vs,
    listingnamefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{yellow},%
    captionfont=\sffamily\color{white},captionbgcolor=gray,%
    fvset={frame=bottomline,framerule=4pt,rulecolor=\color{gray}},
    listingname=Some Listing Name
}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\AtBeginDocument
{
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{section}
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{subsection}
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{subsubsection}
    % Numbering for pyglisting
    \renewcommand{\thepllisting}
    {%
        \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
     \thesection.\arabic{pllisting}%
        \else
     \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
      \thesubsection.\arabic{pllisting}%
     \else
      \thesubsubsection.\arabic{pllisting}%
     \fi
        \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}

%List of Pyglist
\listofpyglistings

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
%Sample Listing
\begin{pyglist}[language=c++,caption=SomeSample, listingname=SomeListing]
int main(char[] args)
{
  cout << "hello World";
}
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's written in the `.pyg.lol` file is

```
\contentsline {pyglist}{\hbox to\z@ {1.1.1.1\hss }\hskip 5ex SomeSample}{2}
```

so the space reserved for the numeric label is 5ex, which is too short.

You can patch `\endpyglist` to do differently:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,toc=listof,toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{verbments}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endpyglist}{5ex}{4em}{}{}

\plset{
    style=vs,
    listingnamefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{yellow},%
    captionfont=\sffamily\color{white},captionbgcolor=gray,%
    fvset={frame=bottomline,framerule=4pt,rulecolor=\color{gray}},
    listingname=Some Listing Name
}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\AtBeginDocument
{
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{section}
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{subsection}
    \counterwithin*{pllisting}{subsubsection}
    % Numbering for pyglisting
    \renewcommand{\thepllisting}
    {%
        \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
     \thesection.\arabic{pllisting}%
        \else
     \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
      \thesubsection.\arabic{pllisting}%
     \else
      \thesubsubsection.\arabic{pllisting}%
     \fi
        \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}

%List of Pyglist
\listofpyglistings

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\subsection{Some Subsection}
%Sample Listing
\begin{pyglist}[language=c++,caption=SomeSample, listingname=SomeListing]
int main(char[] args)
{
  cout << "hello World";
}
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a more complex patch we can make `verbments` write something that will be understandable with the `\@dottedtocline` syntax.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\endpyglist}
  {\lol@caption{\rlap{\thepllisting}\hskip 5ex \pl@caption}}
  {\lol@caption{\protect\numberline{\thepllisting}\pl@caption}}
  {}{\ddt}
\renewcommand{\l@pyglist}[2]{%
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.3em}{#1}{#2}
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

I would mention this to the package developer.

Comment: Wow, thank you. What an easy command. I searched for that over 8hours. thank you really much!

Comment: @user3598980 I added a different patch that probably is better, as it allows you to redefine `\l@pyglist` with a suitable `\@dottedtocline` command.

Comment: Thanks again for your work. This seems to be really more confortable. I have also now the easy ability to change it, like i tried in with my first solution ( `\let\l@lstlisting\l@figure`), which provides me the ability, that the numwidth is equal. Thats really helpful. Such things would be fine as an standard in this package